# How to display date in month and year format

Tags: r

I have a date field called date.timestamp in database,which has date values like "Fri Nov 27 20:17:01 IST 2015" .There are lot of records having date.timestamp field. I need to display it as Nov 2015 for all those records in database. How can I do that?

Comment: How did you get this date? What is it's `class` ?

Comment: You will want to read `?format` and `?as.POSIXct` and probably `?strptime`

Comment: If `IST` stands for `Indian Standard Time`, try `vec <- "Fri Nov 27 20:17:01 IST 2015"; format(strptime(sub("IST", "+0530", vec), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y"), "%b %Y")`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `IST` is the Indian Standard Time, which is 5:30 hours ahead of Coordinated Universal Time, one would substitute `IST` for `+0530` and use the format `%z` of `strptime`.

```
vec <- "Fri Nov 27 20:17:01 IST 2015"
format(strptime(sub("IST", "+0530", vec), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y"), "%b %Y")
# [1] "Nov 2015"


vec <- c("Fri Nov 27 20:17:01 IST 2015","Mon Nov 30 20:17:01 IST 2015")
format(strptime(sub("IST", "+0530", vec), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y"), "%b %Y")
# [1] "Nov 2015" "Nov 2015"
```